# Python Does creating/assigning a value to a variable every loop take more memory/time than creating/assigning a variable outside the loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For example:

```
for i in range(5000):
    a = "some words"
    # Other things
```

vs

```
a = "some words"
for i in range(5000):
    # Other things
```

I'd imagine the second would be better, but how much better exactly is it?
It might be more efficient to have some code outside a loop but it also feels easier to debug & read when the varaibles are assigned immediately before they are used.

Comment: Note that it's rather important whether your variable actually contains a (string) literal or something else! If that's just a placeholder, you might want to use something that fits your use-case more closely.

Comment: [Benchmark it.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) First and foremost, make sure your code is expressing what you *mean*. If the value is static, then there's no point to assign it inside the loop. If it changes, then you probably must assign it inside the loop.

Comment: The performance effect (considering time, memory usage would be the same since it is the same variable name) is negligible, but it is best practice to go by example two. It might not be as negligible though when you work with objects / large arrays.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I had a feeling that might be the case. Are there some docs or something where I could read up on which talk about different types of data's behaviour in this sorta case? For my current use it is string literal I'm using but obvs in future this could be about other types of data.

Comment: @deceze I've not benchmarked stuff before, so I wouldn't quite know how to go about it. I saw that post but there seemed to be some disagreements in the comments about what was right.

Comment: @LiorDahan Thanks. I had a feeling it might be this. Assuming a large dataset (so it's not negatable), might it cause some memory issues if you had slow memory, since we'd be reading/writing more frequently to memory, even  if the total amount of memory used is no more?

Comment: @F1rools22 Unless you have a specific use-case, this is effectively a bottomless pit. Python *the language* makes no commitment whatsoever about memory usage or object existence, other than what the worst case is. Python *the implementation* such as CPython or PyPy does not specify how these things work, they just *implement* how they work. We're talking thousands of lines of C code (for CPython) or self-compiling-to-C Python code (for PyPy) here.

Comment: FWIW, a pretty reliable estimate is that the worst case is double memory consumption for the content of ``a``. Unless ``a`` holds a huge object, this will be entirely negligible compared to all the other stuff your program has in memory. That's assuming no side-effects, in which case the two variants are not equivalent to begin with. But "how much better *exactly* is it" is unanswerable in general. What you should be worried about is the cost of *creating* the content again, though, which won't be bound by memory but processing speed.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi That's really informative, thanks. I'm only questioning it because I wrote some code the 'bad' way, looked at it thinking 'That's probably bad' and wanted to see what other ppl had to say on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intuitively, in vanilla cPython in the absence of a just-in-time compiler that might hoist that assignment out of the loop, we would expect option2 to be faster.

See here for more information on "[compiler hoisting](https://compileroptimizations.com/category/hoisting.htm)".

You can try it for yourself.

```
import timeit

foo = '''
for i in range(5_000):
    a = "some words"
'''

bar = '''
a = "some words"
for i in range(5_000):
    pass
'''

print(timeit.timeit(foo, number=10_000))
print(timeit.timeit(bar, number=10_000))
```

Gives me:

```
1.3565055000000001
0.9187005000000001
```

Note that this difference in speed is likely meaningless though compared to anything else your app is doing and I would recommend you go with whatever you feel is the easiest to understand and maintain.